# How to prevent type scoping in such situation?

Tags: haskell

```hs
instance IsString Escaped where fromString a = Escaped a
instance ConvertibleStrings URI.URI String where convertString = show

data Escaped = forall a. ConvertibleStrings a String => Escaped a
instance Show Escaped where show (Escaped a) = cs a
class Escaping a where
    esc1 :: a -> Escaped
    esc2 :: a -> Escaped
instance ConvertibleStrings a String => Escaping a where
    esc1 a = Escaped $ escape1 $ cs a
    esc2 a = Escaped $ escape2 $ cs a
```

Now, with the `OverloadedStrings` extension enabled, if I use `esc1`, `esc2` then I should use it with type "tag" like: `[sec1 ("a"::String), ...]`. How to prevent it, so to have just a `[sec1 "a", ...]`? Is it possible? I tried DS extension but it does not help in this situation.

Comment: Why not just define `esc1S = esc1 :: String -> Escaped` and then use that?

Comment: I am using it with different types (URIs, Text, String, ByteString...). But OK, it's an option

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I tried DS extension

I assume by “DS extension” you mean `DefaultSignatures`. That lets you specify a default signature for a typeclass method when an instance does not implement the method. It’s typically used for `Generic` deriving code, not cases like this.

If you wanted to specify the default type of a string literal, you probably wanted to use a [`default` declaration](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/decls.html#sect4.3.4), which specifies the types to search when solving an ambiguous type. But the *default* `default` declaration when [`OverloadedStrings`](https://downloads.haskell.org/%7Eghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/glasgow_exts.html#extension-OverloadedStrings) is enabled is `default (Integer, Double, String)`, so `String` should already be chosen if it’s possible to do so. If you still get ambiguities, there’s a different reason, most likely caused by the `ConvertibleString` or `Escaping` classes, which don’t have the built-in defaulting rules that `IsString` does.

However, there is a much simpler solution here that will avoid the ambiguities in the first place. This type:

```
data Escaped
  = forall a. ConvertibleStrings a String
  => Escaped a
```

Or its equivalent with `GADTs` syntax:

```
data Escaped where
  Escaped :: (ConvertibleStrings a String) => a -> Escaped
```

Is an example of what’s known as the *existential antipattern*. It says that `Escaped` contains a value of some hidden type `a` which has an instance of `ConvertibleStrings a String`. But the *only* method of that class is `convertString`, which here has the type `a -> String` for the hidden `a`. That means that the *only* thing you’re allowed to do with an `Escaped` is use it as a `String`! So it’s far simpler to just store a `String`, and furthermore use a `newtype` since there’s only one field:

```
newtype Escaped = Escaped String
```

Thanks to laziness, this `String` won’t be evaluated unless it’s used, so you don’t need to worry about that. In fact, storing the typeclass constraint in an existential is slightly *more* costly than this.

Furthermore, this pattern will often lead to ambiguities:

```
class Escaping a where
    esc1 :: a -> Escaped
    esc2 :: a -> Escaped

instance ConvertibleStrings a String => Escaping a where
    esc1 a = Escaped $ escape1 $ cs a
    esc2 a = Escaped $ escape2 $ cs a
```

It says that *all types* are instances of `Escaping`, because the “instance head” is `Escaping a`. Any constraints on an instance, like `ConvertibleStrings a String` here, are only checked *after* the fact, when the instance is used.

You can try to solve these ambiguities by constraining the types using type annotations (`cs :: a -> String`) or `TypeApplications` (`cs @a @String`) to make the type arguments concrete, but a much simpler solution here is to just make `esc1` and `esc2` into ordinary functions that require a `ConvertibleStrings` constraint, rather than typeclass methods:

```
esc1 :: (ConvertibleStrings a String) => a -> Escaped
esc1 a = Escaped $ escape1 $ cs a

esc2 :: (ConvertibleStrings a String) => a -> Escaped
esc2 a = Escaped $ escape2 $ cs a
```

(Again, the only thing you can do with a `forall a. (ConvertibleStrings a String) => a` is convert it to a `String`, so this is also equivalent to `String -> Escaped`, although it might be more convenient to do the conversion in this function than at every call site.)

In general, a typeclass with a single parameter represents a *set* of types, and a typeclass with multiple parameters like `ConvertibleStrings` represents a *relation* or *function* between types. `ConvertibleStrings` already represents the type relationship you want; `esc1` and `esc2` can simply *use* that relationship. Most of the time you can (and should!) solve a problem with just data types and functions, without making your own typeclass.

Comment: > `newtype Escaped = Escaped String`.I use it for `URI` also, not just strings.

Comment: @Paul-AG: I understand, I only meant to explain that in the code in your question, `data Escaped` is equivalent to `String`. Of course, that may or may not be what you *want*. I hope the rest of the answer was useful, anyway.